# Зацикливание обобщений C#

Tags: c#, generics

Делаю граф и хочу чтобы дуги и вершины были универсальными для соответствующих типов

```
public interface IVertex<TVertex, TEdge>
        where TVertex : IVertex<?>
        where TEdge : IEdge<?>
{
    bool AddEdge(TEdge e);
    TEdge FindEdge(TVertex v);
}

public interface IEdge<TVertex> where TVertex : IVertex<?>
{
    TVertex From { get; }
}
```

Но получается что они зацикливаются, дуга требует тип вершины и наоборот
Как выйти из ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что ваш дизайн классов не вполне верно моделирует отношение между объектами. У вас ребро строится из вершин, поэтому интерфейс параметризируется типом вершины. А вершина почему-то у вас управляет рёбрами.

Давайте приблизим объектную структуру к реальности. На деле связи между вершинами и рёбрами есть *граф*, вот и давайте выделим его отдельной сущностью.

Получится так:

```
interface IVertex
{
}

interface IEdge<V> where V : IVertex
{
    V From { get; }
    V To { get; }
}

interface IGraph<V, E> where V : IVertex where E : IEdge<V>
{
    bool AddEdge(E e);
    E FindEdge(V vfrom);
}
```

Comment: Комментарии по поводу минуса?